# python regex: get name of named group

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this:

```
$ pattern = re.compile('(?P<group1>AAA|BBB|CCC)|(?P<group2>DDD|EEE|FFF)')
```

If I'm looking at a match object I'm not really interested which specific text was matched, I just want to know if it was group1 or group2

groupdict() gives me something like this:

```
$ match.groupdict()
$ {'group1': None, 'group2': 'DDD'}
```

Now, of course, I could find out that it's group2 by just iterating over the dict, but that seems slow if I have a lot of matches to check.
Is there a more direct way to get the group name? (Python 2.7)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe [`lastgroup`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.lastgroup)?

```
>>> pattern = re.compile('(?P<group1>AAA|BBB|CCC)|(?P<group2>DDD|EEE|FFF)')
>>> m = pattern.search("AAA")
>>> m.lastgroup
'group1'
>>> m = pattern.search("DDD")
>>> m.lastgroup
'group2'
```

Comment: Well, I feel a bit sheepish about my question now, the answer looks just to easy x) Thanks!